# Spring boot SQL Server - Slow application load

Tags: sql-server, spring, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc

I am using spring boot with SQL server. On application startup or running integration test, it takes 1 - 2 minutes to load. The spring debug log shows that most of the time is consumed in getting JDBC connection. Below is the log snippet.

```
2014-11-18_15:54:54.604 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2014-11-18_15:55:58.213 [main] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

I am using net.sourceforge.jtds ver 1.3.1 driver and sql server version 2012. Can anyone please help how I can fix this issue.

Comment: Check your database and connection settings (and your physical connection) you also might want to try the microsoft JDBC drivers instead of the `net.sourceforge.jtds` drivers. And I suggest an actual connectionpool (I assume that you use the `DriverManagerDataSource` here).

Comment: For connection pooling, I am using the spring boot default settings

Comment: Then I suggest trying another driver instead of the one you are using now. It hasn't been updated for quite a while and is "only" a JDBC3 and not a JDBC 4.0 / 4.1 implementation.